# printing with Epson TM-T20 from Open Frameworks?

Tags: c++, serial-port, openframeworks, epson, thermal-printer

My ultimate goal is to get the two TM-T20 epson printers printing from Open Frameworks (a c++ toolkit for creative coding.) But at this point I would be happy with them printing at all in any application!

I am using the thermal printers I mentioned above and a RS-232 to usb connection (I'm pretty sure I installed the right drivers). I am developing on a mountain lion MacBookpro in xcode.

The frustrating thing was that I was able to get it working once in coolTerm by connecting to it and then typing and pressing enter, but then couldn't replicate the results once I restarted the computer. In both xcode/Open Frameworks and Coolterm it is able to successfully make the connection using either cu.usbtoserial or tty.usbtoserial (It is also listed as tty.PL2303-00004006 and cu.PL2303-00004006 in my dev folder) but then it won't print if I repeat what worked initially in coolTerm or by trying any of the following in Open Frameworks:

Method 1:

```
ofSerial serial;
serial.setup("/dev/cu.usbserial",38400);
unsigned char myByte = 225;
unsigned char buf[3] = {'o', 'f', '!'};
serial.writeBytes(&buf[0], 3);
```

Method 2:

```
ofSerial mySerial;
mySerial.setup("/dev/cu.usbserial",38400);
unsigned char myByte = 225;
bool byteWasWritten = mySerial.writeByte(myByte);
if ( !byteWasWritten )
    printf("byte was not written to serial port");
```

Method 3 (this is using a newly made open frameworks addon https://github.com/bakercp/ofxESCPOSPrinter for epson thermal printers ):

```
DefaultSerialPrinter printer;
ofBuffer buffer("this is a test\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
printer.writeBytes(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(buffer.getBinaryBuffer()),buffer.size());
printer.flush();
```

I am working to get this running on a tight deadline and I would really appreciate advice on how to move it forward!

Comment: I saw Joshua Noble do an openFrameworks project with a thermal printer before... maybe message him directly on the oF Forum to get a hold of him?

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will try shooting him an email.

Comment: I have figured this out and I will post an explanation when I have time and if there is any interest.